# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed openpyxl through pip.

openpyxl package is present in below path

```
..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
```

> I am using pycharm

In my code if I type

> import openpyxl

openpyxl is highlighted with red color. If we move the cursor over openpyxl.Given below message is displayed

> NO MODULE NAMED OPENPYXL

If I run the code ,I get the below error

```
import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Comment: check whether that path is in `sys.path` list

Comment: @yklsga how to check that

Comment: `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)`

Comment: Did it install correctly? `python -m pip list`

Comment: @jeromino Yes it did install correctly

Comment: Is it also there when you do `import pip; print(pip.get_installed_distributions())` from inside your code? Just to make sure it didn't go into a different Python installation.

Answer (score 6):

Goto File>Settings>Project>Project Interpreter

Hit +

Search openpyxl

Click Install Package

This is how you install packages easily in pycharm instead of pip

Comment: you lost me at search. 'pip3 install openpyxl' in terminal worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by moving the openpyxl folder from D:\Python 3.8.5\Lib\site-packages to D:\Python 3.8.5\Lib\